# OAuth authentication for Google API with Qt

Tags: c++, api, qt, oauth

I'm trying to get authenticated for receiving and publishing Google Buzz-es from a Qt 4.6(c++) application. I'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

Could anyone provide some working solution for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try kQOAuth which is a new Qt library for doing OAuth authentication. It will let you do the user authentication very easily too, if you like.

Supports OAuth 1.0 and HMAC-SHA1. No external dependencies.

http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2010/10/introducing-kqoauth-easy-and-powerful-oauth-library-for-qt/

Comment: Google's API currently uses OAuth 2.0. Does kQOAuth still work?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any either, so I made one: https://github.com/pipacs/steps/tree/master/o2 . Based on KQOAuth, tested with Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search gave me [QOAuth](http://blog.ayoy.net/2009/6/24/oauth), which is a Qt lib and [liboath](http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/) which is a C based API.

Comment: I've tried with QOAuth, but I get always rejected, because of endless parameters for each token, which can't be sent with this lib.

about liboauth - it can't be embed in Maemo devices. I'm looking for a big cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using QOAuth, you have to do some hack before you can use QOAuth in windows.

So far, I could get the request token from Google, and let the user authorize it.
But when I try to get the access token with the oauth_verifier, it keeps telling me the signature is invalid.

Anyway, I've used QOAuth to deal with other SP successfully. So the QOAuth is the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in conversation with the QOAuth developer, who's trying to do everything to make it working with google api, and I'm to the same place... it doesn't recognize my oauth_vertifier, for some reason